# Javascript Not (a==b) || Not (c==b)

Tags: javascript, comparison, logical-operators

I have been trying to get the following compare operator to work.  The second 'if' always executes the next statement in the code.  What I want is to be able to detect when eith entryType OR followupEntryType is not equal to the string "Long Term Care"  Here is the code...

```
function getComboB(sel) {

    var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    if (value == "Rehab") {
        if (!(document.getElementById('entryType').value == "Long Term Care") || !(document.getElementById('followupEntryType').value == "Long Term Care")) {
            document.getElementById('followupEntryType').value = "Long Term Care";
            alert("short-term rehab code");
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("long-term rehab code");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: And by the way, not indenting is a sure way to spend too much time trying to see why a code isn't working.

Comment: Reformat your code with [this](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: If it helps to understand it better, you can refactor the condition as `!(document.getElementById('entryType').value == "Long Term Care" && document.getElementById('followupEntryType').value == "Long Term Care")`

Comment: !A || !B == !(A && B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getComboB(sel) {

var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; 
if (value == "Rehab") {
  if (document.getElementById('entryType').value != "Long Term Care" && document.getElementById('followupEntryType').value != "Long Term Care") {
    document.getElementById('followupEntryType').value = "Long Term Care";
    alert ("short-term rehab code");
    return true;
  } else {
    alert ("long-term rehab code");
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: After reviewing my code preceding the function getComboB(sel), I realized I had a logic error.  However, I did change if statement to this one and with the change in code this if works.  I thank all who contributed suggestions to this issue.  They all provided good nsight.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's going on, is that what you want?

```
if(true || true)
{
console.log('second check will not be executed');
}

if(true || false)
{
console.log('second check will not be executed');
}

if(false || false)
{
console.log('second check will be executed');
}

if(false || true)
{
console.log('second check will be executed');
}
```

If you want to check whether EITHER is false, you should use `&&`, and move your code in the `else` block

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestion.   I could, I think, make the code much simply by the following:

Comment: Sorry, but I will have to follow up on this later.

Answer (score 0):

No, the second `if` doesn't always execute the next statement. If both the values are `"Long Term Care"`, then it will execute the code in the `else` part. I.e.:

```
<input type="text" id="entryType" value="Long Term Care" />
<input type="text" id="followupEntryType" value="Long Term Care" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QW43B/

If you want the condition to be true if both values are different from `"Long Term Care"` (i.e. it will go into the `else` if either value is `"Long Term Care"`), you should use the `&&` operator instead:

```
if (!(document.getElementById('entryType').value == "Long Term Care") && !(document.getElementById('followupEntryType').value == "Long Term Care")) {
```